# Execute method of the embeded component with Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a vuejs component("Main") with a dialog and I use a subcomponent("SpeechToText") into it.

When I´m going to open the dialog, I need to check if   "speechInititalized" of the "SpeechToText " is true.
if yes, I´d like to call a "reset method" to stop the microphone and the user can restart as if were the first time.

How could I do that?
Here is a snippet of the code.

//Main component

```
<template>
  <div>  
      <v-dialog v-model="dialogSpeech" hide-overlay persistent width="700">
            <SpeechToText></SpeechToText>
            <v-btn color="info" @click="closeDialogSpeech">Fechar</v-btn>
    </v-dialog>
</div>
</template>
data:()=>({
   speechInititalized:false,
}),
methods:{
    closeDialogSpeech(){
     this.dialogSpeech = false;
    }
    openDialogSpeech(){
        //I´d like to call reset method of the SpeechToText component if it was initialized
        if (speechInititalized){ //from SpeechToText data
            reset(); //from SpeechToText data
        }
    }
}
```

//SpeechToText

```
data:()=>({
    speechInititalized:false,
})
mounted(){
 this.initialize();
}
methods{
    initialize(){
        //speech api is initialized
        speechInititalized=true;
    };
    reset(){
       //speech api is stopped
       //stop microphone
       //clear data
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't check if speech was initialized in parent component. That's child component's responsibility. All you do in parent component is emit/announce the dialogue has opened.

Child component reacts to this announcement.

Proof of concept:

// parent

```
<template>
  ...
  <speech-to-text :is-dialogue-open="isDialogueOpen" />
  ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
 ...
  data: () => ({
    isDialogueOpen: false // set this to true/false when dialogue is opened/closed
  }),
  ...
}
```

// child:

```
export default {
  props: {
    isDialogueOpen: {
      type: boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  ...,
  watch: {
    isDialgueOpen(value) {
      // reset if dialogue has just opened and speech has previously been initialized
      if (value && this.speechInitialized) {
        this.reset();
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

---

Another, more flexible and cleaner approach, preferable when the relation between parent and child is not as direct, or even dynamic and, generally, preferable in larger scale applications, is to use an `eventBus` (basically a singleton shared across components for emitting/listening to events).

Emit an event on the bus in any corner of the application and have as many listeners reacting to that event in as many other components in the app, regardless of their relation to the original emitter component.

Here's a [neat example](https://css-tricks.com/using-event-bus-to-share-props-between-vue-components/) explaining the concept in more detail.

If you're using typescript, you might want to give [vue-bus-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bus-ts) a try.

This approach is similar to the previous one (emit an event when dialogue is opened and react to it in SpeechToText component), except both parent and child are now cleaner (none of them needs the `isDialogueOpen` prop, and you also get rid of the `watch` - whenever possible, avoid watch in Vue as it's more expensive than most alternatives).
Since the event listener is inside SpeechToText, you can check if speech has already been initialized.

Another benefit of this approach is that you don't have to emit/change anything when dialogue closes (unless you want to react to that event as well).